# How to connect mysql in docker subnet(172.18) from my local host Windows(192.168)?

Tags: mysql, docker, networking

my host machine ip is `192.168.8.100`

Here are my ipconfig in Windows10

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : DHCP HOST

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cd90:1c37:f269:c1b5%10
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.21.93.241
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a80e:8b65:b853:7976%13
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.75.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::dcad:f104:d3ff:60f%7
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Npcap Loopback Adapter:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f85f:91c6:fcb6:c971%21
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.201.113
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e58a:9017:15ae:2a26%17
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.100
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.8.1
```

I create a new subnet from docker
From `docker-compose.yml`

```
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: onlinecodedb
    volumes:
    - onlinecode-database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysqlrootpassword
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlpassword
    MYSQL_USER: mysql
    MYSQL_DATABASE: onlinecode
    ports:
    - "3300:3306"
    networks:
    - onlinecode-net

networks:
onlinecode-net:
    driver: bridge
```

From `docker network inspect onlinecode_onlinecode-net`

```
[
    {
        "Name": "onlinecode_onlinecode-net",
        "Id": "b915ecd03a9acdb0d28b8b355dca0a479a186c2b5e6fbb35efb81de1684aa63d",
        "Created": "2018-10-02T02:17:36.4110372Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0730d1115929f5b476116fd6147782bf15d7f469fb7203779d2d8f5953bdea49": {
                "Name": "onlinecodeapp",
                "EndpointID": "aa0c0bf03740e500821b1f00d0da2f09d3642723035e0b2e384ac18746bf182a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c3abc13980d415dd0a6494e3e5113847448e004f3b720f1603c826ebbaa2b9db": {
                "Name": "onlinecodedb",
                "EndpointID": "7e5261e88fcded21e1864906de976ed1c2d5b30d4c94ae65375bf21e0035706c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "onlinecode-net",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "onlinecode",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.22.0"
        }
    }
]
```

`onlinecodedb` in ip `B class range` but my localhost in `C range`

So how I connect to mysql from 192.168 to 172.18 ?
I cannot find same question from stackoverflow

I have googled two days, someone said: hey, you should use Gateway and Router.

But How I map 172 to 192? all of them are private IP, not public.

I know this question is stupid, this is a computer network problem, but please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Networking features in Docker for Windows: [Known limitations, use cases, and workarounds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds). The recommended way is to `publish` a port to the host.

Comment: Your docker engine is in windows 10 host machine or in virtualbox ..?

Comment: @Prem it's Docker On Windows Kernel Version: 4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs
Operating System: Docker for Windows
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.934GiB

Comment: @Prem Windows 10 pro hypervisor.. not VBox

Comment: Then you should try with localhost:3300, this might work because as per my understanding you are trying to connect from application running in the host to the docker container(mysql container).

Comment: @Prem OMG, I think I type "3306:3306", not "3300:3306", so I all try connect 3306.. But I am not clear, they are subnet, Did B class ip and C class ip can direct access not through gateway?

Comment: Let me know if it is  working then i will explain what is the issue..

Comment: @Prem Yes!! but how it work? my bad network knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using localhost:3300 to connect to mysql container.

First when your docker engine is installed in your local machine, by default docker is running in  localhost (ie) 127.0.0.1 ipaddress.

As per your docker-compose file

```
ports:
- "3300:3306"
```

3306 port is exposed inside the container and connects with 3300 port of the host machine.

Next you mentioned about Ipaddress of the container

```
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
            }
        ]
```

This is a  network you have created with the name **onlinecode-net**". This network is created by docker-engine which is used internally  to connect between the containers which is not exposed in the host machine.

Comment: Since it's a common point of confusion: `docker run -p` ports are accessible via 127.0.0.1 or `localhost` _only from browsers or other tools running directly on the host system_.  Other containers think "localhost" means "my private container namespace" and can't reach other containers that way.